# Hospital database: finding instances of Health Card Numbers appearing on more than one Health Record

Tags: sql, ms-access

In Ontario, each resident is assigned one Health Card Number (HCN).
At our hospital, patients are assigned a Medical Record Number (MRN).

I'm wanting to find instances where one HCN appears on multiple MRN's (this can be caused by clerks creating a new MRN even when one already exists for a patient/HCN).

I want the output to list just one example of each 'duplicate' MRN created, with other data to allow for good, quick decisions to be made about whether to merge the records or not (eg:  birthdate, name, address fields, email address).

Tables I have include:

- list of MRN, Name, Birthdate
- a table which links the MRN to a 'unique record number' (Urn) used in the following tables
- list of Urn and HCN
- list of Urn and Patient address

I'm using Microsoft Access, and have set up the relations. I've tried some different code, but could use some help. I'm still learning SQL and can't get it right with this yet.

This is the baseline code Access generates:

```
SELECT [HCN, Mri Urn].[Edited HCN], [MRN, Name, DOB].[Medical Record],
   [MRN, Name, DOB].Name, [MRN, Name, DOB].Birthdate, 
   [Pat Address, Adm Urn].[Pat City], [Pat Address, Adm Urn].[Pat Street],
   [Pat Address, Adm Urn].[Pat Street2], [Pat Address, Adm Urn].[Pat Email],
   [Pat Address, Adm Urn].[Pat Home Phone]
FROM [Pat Address, Adm Urn] 
INNER JOIN ([MRN, Name, DOB] 
INNER JOIN ([HCN, Mri Urn] 
INNER JOIN [ADM's Mri Urn-Adm Urn link] 
   ON [HCN, Mri Urn].Urn = [ADM's Mri Urn-Adm Urn link].[Mri Urn]) 
   ON [MRN, Name, DOB].[Medical Record] = [ADM's Mri Urn-Adm Urn link].[Mri Urn]) 
   ON [Pat Address, Adm Urn].Urn = [ADM's Mri Urn-Adm Urn link].Urn
ORDER BY [HCN, Mri Urn].[Edited HCN], 
   [MRN, Name, DOB].[Medical Record], 
   [MRN, Name, DOB].Name, 
   [MRN, Name, DOB].Birthdate, 
   [Pat Address, Adm Urn].[Pat City], 
   [Pat Address, Adm Urn].[Pat Street], 
   [Pat Address, Adm Urn].[Pat Street2], 
   [Pat Address, Adm Urn].[Pat Email], 
   [Pat Address, Adm Urn].[Pat Home Phone];
```

Comment: I know I would get blames, but anyway, if you want to learn SQL and databases, and especially in a health facility, do not try to use access as a database. One very good alternative would be postgreSQL or MS SQL Server if you want to use something MS based. Apart from that, do your tables really have those names?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Cetin! Actually, I extracted the tables to Excel files, some of which I named in funky ways =P I will try using postgreSQL and connect directly to the database, instead of creating the in-between spreadsheets.

Answer (score 0):

Your tables are rather hard to follow due to their namings :) I am not sure if this is what you meant (not having any sample data makes it harder to understand):

```
SELECT 
[HCN, Mri Urn].[Edited HCN],
       [MRN, Name, DOB].[Medical Record],
       [MRN, Name, DOB].Name,
       [MRN, Name, DOB].Birthdate,
       [Pat Address, Adm Urn].[Pat City],
       [Pat Address, Adm Urn].[Pat Street],
       [Pat Address, Adm Urn].[Pat Street2],
       [Pat Address, Adm Urn].[Pat Email],
       [Pat Address, Adm Urn].[Pat Home Phone]
FROM [Pat Address, Adm Urn]
    INNER JOIN([MRN, Name, DOB]
    INNER JOIN([HCN, Mri Urn]
    INNER JOIN [ADM's Mri Urn-Adm Urn link]
        ON [HCN, Mri Urn].Urn = [ADM's Mri Urn-Adm Urn link].[Mri Urn])
        ON [MRN, Name, DOB].[Medical Record] = [ADM's Mri Urn-Adm Urn link].[Mri Urn])
        ON [Pat Address, Adm Urn].Urn = [ADM's Mri Urn-Adm Urn link].Urn
where  [ADM's Mri Urn-Adm Urn link].Urn in 
(select urn from  [ADM's Mri Urn-Adm Urn link]
group by URN having count(*) > 1)
ORDER BY [HCN, Mri Urn].[Edited HCN],
         [MRN, Name, DOB].[Medical Record],
         [MRN, Name, DOB].Name,
         [MRN, Name, DOB].Birthdate,
         [Pat Address, Adm Urn].[Pat City],
         [Pat Address, Adm Urn].[Pat Street],
         [Pat Address, Adm Urn].[Pat Street2],
         [Pat Address, Adm Urn].[Pat Email],
         [Pat Address, Adm Urn].[Pat Home Phone];
```